# Laravel Undefin offset: 0 getResource

Tags: laravel, eloquent, undefined, offset

I've got a probleme when i want to search element in my DB into a function. Here is the code of this function :

```
public function getResource()
{
    $settings = SettingUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return $settings;
}
```

I've cast dd of $settings, and it returns me the right object with right attibutes. But i've got error "Undefined offset: 0". Could you help me please ? Thanks you very much !

Comment: Post your blade view code where you are trying to access the value

Answer (score 1):

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

simply means you are trying to get an offset that doesn't exist. Have a look at this code:

```
{{ $settings[0]->column_name }}
```

in the line, if `[0]` index doesn't exist then it will throw the same `Undefined offset: 0` error. So to deal with it use:

```
{{ $settings[0]->column_name or 'default_value' }}
```

As you are using `first()`, so their is no need of `[0]`, simply use:

```
{{ $settings->column_name }}
```

Comment: But if i write dd($settings), dd returns me the good object with good informations !

Comment: i've posted it !

Comment: The array or the class object you are getting post that

Comment: When i write for exemple 
`$settings = SettingUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
dd($settings->user_id);`
it shows the right id, if i write dd($settings) it shows the right object, but when i want to return it, i've got this error, and that's my problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()` method in order to get multiple objects,

```
$settings = SettingUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: Yes i know, but if i write next to this line `dd($settings[0]);`, it shows the right object. But if i want to return it, i've got this undefined offset 0 error